# If date column (column A) in gridview is today's date, show expired in column B

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webforms

I have a gridview that is getting data from a stored procedure. Column A is a date field. Column B has the text active (for all rows). However, I would like to change the text of 'active' (in the status column) to 'expired' based on the date - so if it's today's date or older, show expired. I know I could execute a job on the SQL server to change the column before importing into my table. However, I would like to only change the text and not alter the DB if possible. So, how would I manipulate the active column to show expired based on today's date.

```
con.Open();
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();                                
   sda.Fill(dt);
   tblMytable.DataSource = dt;
   tblMytable.DataBind();
   con.Close();
}
```

The webform:

```
<asp:GridView ID="tblMytable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>                
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateField" HeaderText="Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make it a TemplateField you have much more control over the data and you can then use a Ternary operator to apply some logic.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateField")) < DateTime.Now ? "Expired" : "Active" %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```